# Unity C# Syntax question - Transform Position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax

What is the reason behind this?

I'm doing the Create with code course and am at a part where I have the main camera follow the player. I got the camera to work but wanted to offset the position slightly so I thought this would work:

```
void Update()
{
    transform.position = player.transform.position + Vector3 (0,5, -5);
}
```

After Watching the video, I see that I needed to add *new* to the text so that it could say this.

```
void Update()
{
    transform.position = player.transform.position + *new* Vector3 (0,5, -5);
}
```

What is the reason behind this? I get that it is a new vector, but I'm trying to reason this and find out where I could learn more on proper syntax - I assume the documentation?

Comment: Yes, read the c# documentation.  Here is the section for [Creating Instances of Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/objects).  You can find links to other reference material in the left sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"vector3" is empty. A new assignment is required.
"new vector3" is used to create vector3 struct.
Because "vector3" is a struct, you need to create a new one to use.

Comment: As a note, you do not need to `new` a struct, because it is a value type.  `Instances of structs can also be created by using the new operator, but this isn't required`  eg. `Vector3 v3; v3.x = 2;`